# Is an images table best practice for an ecommerce site?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-s3, database-schema

I'm building an ecommerce system with products and variants, where each has between 1 and 5 images that are stored on Amazon S3. Is it considered best practice to have a separate images table where I store the S3 URLs, or is acceptable to just add 5 image columns to each of the products and variants tables? Having a separate images table means that on import I need to do 6 SELECTS and then INSERTS (to make sure the product and each of its images don't already exist and then to import them) rather than 1. And, on retrieval, I need to join the images table to the products table 5 times to have it return the images with the product, like this:

```
SELECT prd."id" AS id, prd."title" AS title, prd."description" AS description,
  prd."createdAt" AS productcreatedate, 
  prdPic1."url" AS productpic1,
  prdPic2."url" AS productpic2,
  prdPic3."url" AS productpic3,
  prdPic4."url" AS productpic4,
  prdPic5."url" AS productpic5,
  brd."name" AS brandname, brd."id" AS brandid, 
  cat."name" AS categoryname, cat."id" AS categoryid, 
  prt."name" AS partnername, prt."id" AS partnerid
FROM "Products" prd
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Pictures" prdPic1 ON prdPic1."entityId" = prd."id" AND prdPic1."entity" = '1'
 AND prdPic1."sortOrder" = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Pictures" prdPic2 ON prdPic2."entityId" = prd."id" AND prdPic2."entity" = '1'
 AND prdPic2."sortOrder" = 2
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Pictures" prdPic3 ON prdPic3."entityId" = prd."id" AND prdPic3."entity" = '1'
 AND prdPic3."sortOrder" = 3
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Pictures" prdPic4 ON prdPic4."entityId" = prd."id" AND prdPic4."entity" = '1'
 AND prdPic4."sortOrder" = 4
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Pictures" prdPic5 ON prdPic5."entityId" = prd."id" AND prdPic5."entity" = '1'
 AND prdPic5."sortOrder" = 5
INNER JOIN "Brands" brd ON brd."id" = prd."BrandId"
INNER JOIN "Categories" cat ON cat."id" = prd."CategoryId"
INNER JOIN "Partners" prt ON prt."id" = brd."PartnerId";
```

The value of normalizing Brands, Categories, and Partners is clear to me to reduce redundancy. I'm less clear on the value for an images table. Explain Analyze on Postgres says this query takes 3310 msec to return 22000 rows. However, I haven't created indexes on Pictures yet, so that's not a fair analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, I think I would add single column, of text[] type (array of text). In this way, you have the images where you need them, and you're not bound to end in hell when you'll add more images for a product.